# Code not working

Tags: angularjs

What is the issue with this angularJS code? It is not working.

This line has some issue:

```
You are entering: {{student.fullName()}}
```

Complete code is as below:

```
<html>

<head>
<script type = "javascript"  src = "http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.3.14/angular.min.js">
</script>

</head>

<body>
<div ng-app = "mainApp" ng-controller = "studentController">
         Enter first name: <input type = "text" ng-model = "student.firstName"><br><br>
         Enter last name: <input type = "text" ng-model = "student.lastName"><br>
         <br>

         You are entering: {{student.fullName()}}
</div>


      <script>
         var mainApp = angular.module("mainApp", []);

         mainApp.controller('studentController', function($scope) {
            $scope.student = {
               firstName: "ABCD",
               lastName: "EFGH",

               fullName: function() {
                  var studentObject;
                  studentObject = $scope.student;
                  return studentObject.firstName + " " + studentObject.lastName;
               }
            }
         });
      </script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: It is working good: https://jsfiddle.net/U3pVM/26918/

Comment: @user2249160 yes works because you don't include angular with `type="javascript"`. Replace with this: `<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.3.14/angular.min.js">
</script>`

Comment: @gianlucatursi Strange. Even if angular.min.js is a javascript file, you don't have to include type='javascript'.

Comment: @RKh yes but `type="javascript"` doesn't exists :) it's `type="text/javascript"`. Anyway in my comment above i have paste the url wrongly. This is the correct url for your angular version. `http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.3.14/angular.min.js`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Error is in referencing
Use

```
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.4.8/angular.min.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 1):

The angular file is considered to be a text file and not a javascript one. Please change this to the code below:

```
<script type = "text/javascript"  src = "http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.3.14/angular.min.js">
```